# Convert a javascript private key to one usable in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, rsa

How do I convert the JavaScript notation:

```
// JavaScript Code
function decrypt()
{
   // key = [ [d], [p], [q] ];
   var key=[[119141457,185046352,2676254],[40632295,2191],[122927507,2595]];
   document.form.text.value=rsaDecode(key, document.form.text.value);
}
```

I am referring to the variable key, to one usable in PHP:

```
// PHP Code
$privateKey = "[[119141457,185046352,2676254],[40632295,2191],[122927507,2595]]";
openssl_private_decrypt($encryptedData, $sensitiveData, $privateKey);
```

This question is derived from the Stack Overflow second response:
[How to encrypt data in javascript and decrypt in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414064/how-to-encrypt-data-in-javascript-and-decrypt-in-php)

Basically, I am not familiar with the JavaScript notation `var myVariable = [[1234], [4321], etc.]`.  What exactly does that do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement:

```
var key=[[119141457,185046352,2676254],[40632295,2191],[122927507,2595]];
```

is a declaration and initialization of **2 dimensional array** in Javascript.

In PHP equivalent key variable would be:

```
$privateKey = array ( array(119141457,185046352,2676254), array(40632295,2191),
                      array(122927507,2595)
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I am not familiar with the JavaScript notation var myVariable = [[1234], [4321], etc.]. What exactly does that do?

It is an Array and in each index there is another array.

[MDN Example: 3A. Creating a two-dimensional array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Example.3A_Creating_a_two-dimensional_array)