# Decryption of encrypted text in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, cryptico

I am trying to decode encrypted data in PHP, however the return value keeps coming back as null.

The data to be decrypted comes into the PHP file as a data argument.

```
$dataArg1 = $_REQUEST["data"];

// Retrieve $encryptedData from storage ...
//
// Load the private key and decrypt the encrypted data
$encryptedData = $dataArg1;
$privateKey = array ( array(123456,654321,123456), array(123456,1234),
                      array(1234567,4321)
                    );
    openssl_private_decrypt($encryptedData, $sensitiveData, $privateKey);
```

The function above comes from the second response of another posting here on Stack Overflow:
[How to encrypt data in javascript and decrypt in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414064/how-to-encrypt-data-in-javascript-and-decrypt-in-php)

I assume that the decrypted value is in the PHP variable, $sensitiveData.

When I echo that to the screen, I get nothing.

```
echo("sensitiveData=[$sensitiveData]<br />");
```

Thoughts?

UPDATE:
The return value from openssl_private_decrypt() is FALSE, and the return value is NULL.

UPDATE 2:
I created the public/private key from the following URL.
http://shop-js.sourceforge.net/crypto2.htm

At the bottom, there is the line:
    And put the following in your private script (probably on your local hard disk -- not on the internet -- if your private key is found this whole thing is useless.)

```
<script>
function decrypt() {
 // key = [ [d], [p], [q] ];
 var key=[[123456789,123456789,123456789],[123456789,1234],[123456789,4321]];
 document.form.text.value=rsaDecode(key, document.form.text.value);
}
</script>
(actual values changed)
```

I copied translated the "var key=" line to PHP (per my other posting).  Translation above using embedded arrays.  I then past that key to the decrypt function.

My thought is that the PHP documentation calls the private key "mixed".  I am wondering if maybe I need a different format for the private key.

Here is the output:

```
dataArg1=[jmOdss9ktFc\"WO5eltUZXt0rpqS1NluNKa]

bResult=[]

sensitiveData=[]

var_dump=[NULL ]
```

Comment: How exactly was the data encrypted to begin with? Why do you think that's your private key exactly?

Comment: Why do you think it's `NULL` and not `false` or empty string? Have you tried to see `var_dump($sensitiveData);`? And what `openssl_private_decrypt()` returns in your case?

Comment: I did not know about var_dump().  Thank you.  I updated my question.  The return value from the function is FALSE and the data value, not surprisingly, is NULL.  I used var_dump() to gather the NULL and echoed the return value.

Comment: I encrypted the data in JavaScript using the first part of the response in the other Stack Overflow question.  I verified that the JavaScript side works, which it does.  I was able to encrypt and decrypt.  I verified that I can pass the encrypted data, and I verified that I can construct the private key in a usable format in PHP.  That was the subject of another question.  I did change the private key above from the real values to some junk ones, though.

Comment: did you check if $dataArg1 is null or not?

Comment: I already echoed that as well. I am calling the PHP from my browser setting the address bar.  I tried with both a stripslash and without it.  When I echoed the encrypted data, I had to add a stripslash to get the echoed value to match what I saw in Visual Studio on the JavaScript side.

Comment: "The first part of the response in another question..." - That's not very helpful, as there are several responses with several links to several external sites. Please clarify what algorithm you're using exactly and how you created your public/private keys.

Comment: What's the output from echo $sensitiveData? You're renaming $dataArg1 to $encryptedData.

Comment: I added the output from all the variables at the end of my question, see above.

Answer (score 1):

$privateKey has to be in a certain format. You can't just throw in random data to it and magically expect it to know what to do with it.

Also, looking at the js you're using, it's not just doing RSA. It has a function named `base64ToText`. It's decoding the ciphertext with that, taking the first byte as the length of the "encrypted session key", getting the "encrypted session key", decrypting that with RSA and then using that as the key to RC4 to decrypt it. But there are a number of problems with that too. Among other things, `base64ToText` isn't the same thing as PHP's `base64_encode` as the name might imply.

Anyway I wasn't able to get it to working. Personally, I'd recommend something more like this (which is interoperable with PHP / [phpseclib's Crypt_RSA](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net)):

http://area51.phpbb.com/phpBB/viewtopic.php?p=208860

That said, I did manage to figure a few things out. Your js lib uses base-28. To convert numbers from that format to one phpseclib uses you'll need to use this function:

```
function conv_base($num)
{
    $result = pack('N', $num[count($num) - 1]);

    for ($i = count($num) - 2; $i >= 0; --$i) {
        _base256_lshift($result, 28);
        $result = $result | str_pad(pack('N', $num[$i]), strlen($result), chr(0), STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    return $result;
}

function _base256_lshift(&$x, $shift)
{
    if ($shift == 0) {
        return;
    }

    $num_bytes = $shift >> 3; // eg. floor($shift/8)
    $shift &= 7; // eg. $shift % 8

    $carry = 0;
    for ($i = strlen($x) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
        $temp = ord($x[$i]) << $shift | $carry;
        $x[$i] = chr($temp);
        $carry = $temp >> 8;
    }
    $carry = ($carry != 0) ? chr($carry) : '';
    $x = $carry . $x . str_repeat(chr(0), $num_bytes);
}
```

Here's the script I used to confirm the correctness of that:

```
<?php
include('Math/BigInteger.php'); 

$p = array(242843315,241756122,189); 
$q = array(177094647,33319298,129); 
$n = array(45173685,178043534,243390137,201366668,24520); 

$p = new Math_BigInteger(conv_base($p), 256); 
$q = new Math_BigInteger(conv_base($q), 256); 
$n = new Math_BigInteger(conv_base($n), 256); 

$test = $p->multiply($q); 
echo $test . "\r\n" . $n;
```

ie. they match.

I also ported your js's `base64ToText` to PHP:

```
function decode($t)
{
    static $b64s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_"';
    $r = '';
    $m = $a = 0;
    for ($n = 0; $n < strlen($t); $n++) {
        $c = strpos($b64s, $t[$n]);
        if ($c >= 0) {
            if ($m) {
                $r.= chr(($c << (8-$m))&255 | $a);
            }
            $a = $c >> $m;
            $m+=2;
            if ($m == 8) {
                $m = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return $r;
}
```

Among other potential problems I may have encountered...  who knows if their RC4 implementation is correct? Their base64 implementation isn't so it wouldn't be without precedent for the RC4 implementation to be broken too.

Comment: My goal is to encrypt text in JavaScript on the client side (no different than encrypting a password in the link in your example), and decrypting the password on the server PHP side. I am not wedded to any solution, just one that works.  I performed a Google search and came across the method used above, just could not get it to work.  I downloaded the zip file, but the force was not with frostjedi.com, so the demo and source file links did not work.  Evidently, the Emperor did not perish.

Comment: You should be able to copy / paste the source code to that file for use on your site: http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/rsa/index.txt You'll need to also grab a copy of sha1.js since the copy that site is using is locally sourced: http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/rsa/sha1.js